# Django admin dynamic form fields population

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, custom-fields

I have Game model with ManyToMany relation on Taxonomy model witch has multiple types (PLATFORM, GENRE, FEATURE etc.)

```
class Game(models.Model):
    taxonomy = models.ManyToManyField(Taxonomy)

class Taxonomy(models.Model):
    TAXONOMY_ORDER = [
        'PLATFORM',
        'GAME_PROCESS',
        'GRAPHICS',
        'GENRE',
        'CATEGORY',
        'FEATURE'
    ]
    type = models.CharField(choices=TAXONOMY_TYPES.items(), max_length=15)
```

I want to remove `taxonomy` field from admin and add separate MultiplueChoises field for each taxonomy type from `TAXONOMY_ORDER`

```
class GameAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GameAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        taxonomy_active = kwargs['instance'].taxonomy.all().values_list('id', flat=True)

        for tax_type in Taxonomy.
            self.fields['taxonomy_' + tax_type] = forms.MultipleChoiceField()
            self.fields['taxonomy_' + tax_type].queryset = Taxonomy.objects.filter(type=tax_type)
            self.Meta.fields.append('taxonomy_' + tax_type)
            self.initial['taxonomy' + tax_type] = Taxonomy.objects.filter(
                                                    id__in=taxonomy_active,
                                                    type=tax_type
                                                ).values_list('id', flat=True)

class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = GameAdminForm

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = super(GameAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

        for tax_type in Taxonomy.TAXONOMY_ORDER:
            fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] += ['taxonomy_' + tax_type]

        return fieldsets
```

I have two issues with this:

1. When I try add fields dynamicly I recieve an error

   ```
   Unknown field(s) (taxonomy_FEATURE, taxonomy_PLATFORM, taxonomy_CATEGORY, taxonomy_GRAPHICS, taxonomy_GENRE, taxonomy_GAME_PROCESS) specified for Game. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class GameAdmin.
   ```
2. When I try to add custom fields explicitly they are rendered blank

   ```
   class GameAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
       taxonomy_PLATFORM = forms.MultipleChoiceField()
       taxonomy_GAME_PROCESS = forms.MultipleChoiceField()
       taxonomy_GRAPHICS = forms.ChoiceField()
       taxonomy_GENRE = forms.MultipleChoiceField()
       taxonomy_CATEGORY = forms.MultipleChoiceField()
       taxonomy_FEATURE = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           ***__init__ stuff***
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the rep for a comment, so this'll have to be an answer. I have been trying to solve the same problem for my own project, and the best solution I have found is this self-answered question by chadgh: [How do I create and save dynamic fields in Django ModelAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335349/how-do-i-create-and-save-dynamic-fields-in-django-modeladmin).

I have tried this method in my code. It works perfectly, and I think it does exactly what you're trying to accomplish. The only caveat is that in

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    kwargs['fields'] = flatten_fieldsets(self.declared_fieldsets)
    return super(PersonAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

`self.declared_fieldsets` is deprecated as of Django 1.7. I used `self.fieldsets` instead and it worked fine.

The main difficulty is that ModelAdmin normally gets the fields from the form class before it's instantiated, before the form's `__init__` has executed, so it doesn't see the dynamic fields. That's why you have to override `ModelAdmin.get_form`.

Comment: Despite the fact that it's necessary explicitly put down all fields in fieldsets it's the best solution for now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find out hot to solve dynamic MultipleChoiceField population with data, but still looking for proper solution of adding custom dynamic fields to ModelForm.

1. To populate MultipleChoiceField with existing values we need to pass `choises` on initialization:

   ```
   forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choises)
   ```
2. To do that in dynamic way, we need to add our field to `self.fields` in `__init__`

   ```
   self.fields['dynamic_field_name'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choises)
   ```
3. To pass `selected` values:

   ```
   self.initial['dynamic_field_name'] = initial_value
   ```

Complete code:

```
class GameAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dynamic_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GameAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **


        choises = Taxonomy.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name')
        self.fields['dynamic_field'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choises)
        self.initial['dynamic_field'] = active_id_list

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = '__all__'


class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = GameAdminForm
    exclude = ['rating', '_id']

admin.site.register(Game, GameAdmin)
```